# Checkbox exclusion on DIV click

Tags: jquery, html, css, checkbox

I have a simple `div` container, with a formatted `<ul><li>` inside to display contact information. When you click on the `div` it will take you to the page to show their profile. This is working fine.

However, is there a way I can make it so that the `checkbox` is still clickable? At the moment if you click the `checkbox` it acts as if I've clicked the parent `div` so will therefore redirect you away from the page.  So, I would like it to work as it is, but with the ability to still be able to click on the `checkbox`

I have the following mock up, [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YXrwOd)

HTML

```
<div class="contactlist" data-token="ABCDEF">
    <ul>
        <li><input type="checkbox"></li>
        <li><img src="" alt="..." height="50" width="50" /></li>
        <li><span>Mr A Sample</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(".contactlist").on("click", function(e){

  var token = $(this).data('token');
  window.location.href = "contact.php?token="+token;

});
```

PS The `window.location` doesn't work in the CodePen example (they've disabled page redirects), but that normally works, and would redirect you.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Comment: Code in the question is certainly the most helpful.  You don't necessarily need a link to "working" code for most questions to be answered correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *event* object has a `target` property which has a reference to the element  of event origination (which element was actually clicked).  So if the originating element is a *checkbox*, then you can skip the rest of the event logic, like so:

```
// did not click on a checkbox
if(!$(e.target).is(':checkbox'))
```

**Complete JS**

```
$('.contactlist').on('click', function(e) {  
    if(!$(e.target).is(':checkbox')) {
      var token = $(this).data('token');
      window.location.href = 'contact.php?token=' + token;
    }
});
```

Comment: Perfect, this works great!! Thank you.  I'll mark as the accepted answer when the system lets me.